# Safari extensions corrupted

Tags: safari, safari-extensions

I'm attempting to install a Safari extension and I'm getting a error that says:

```
"1Password-4.2.5.safariextz is damaged and can't be open. You should move it to the Trash."
```

I thought maybe the 1Password was actually corrupted so I tried Ghostery and got the same error.

```
“Ghostery.safariextz” is damaged and can’t be opened. You should move it to the Trash.
```

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

I'm on Yosemite 10.10.1 - Safari 8.0

Comment: Did you try redownloading them?

Answer (score 1):

I do know that Safari 8 requires a new extension for 1Password - you need version 5 (which was a free upgrade for folks using v4 if I remember correctly

Comment: You *can* with a bit of juggling still get v3 to work in Yosemite. I never liked the v4 interface, so I rejigged mine with the v4 plugin but the v3 app, a while back on Mavericks - & it still works on Yosemite.

Comment: @TheWellington Sadly, the 1Password app and extension numbers appear to be out of sync. According to my system, 4.2.5 is the current Safari extension, but I'm using 1Password 5.0.2.